# Split blog posts over multiple pages

Tags: paging, nodes

Apologies in advance for the long message but I am very new to Drupal and really have no idea what I'm doing sowill try to explain. My company has there website built in Drupal 7, we have a module installed which allows us to create single page blogs. What we'd like to be able to do is also create blog posts that can be split over multiple pages (if we choose).

As an example, if the user clicked on a particular blog post from our blog page they would be taken to the first page (as they currently do), then, at some point on the page we would like to have a next button which takes them to the second part of the blog post. Then on page 2 they would have the 'previous'/'next' buttons and so on.

I have tried installing a module called Smart Paging which looked like it would do the job, however I cannot for the life of me get it to work. Here is a breakdown of what I have done:

- I've installed the module
- Enabled it
- Selected the 'Default page break method' as 'manual'
- Amended the 'text formats' so 'Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. < br > and < p >) for Smart Paging compatibility' is ticked
- Unticked 'Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. < br > and < p >)'
- Added '' to the 'Limit allowed HTML tags' list
- Move 'Smart Paging' up underneath 'Body' on Administration » Structure » Content types » Blog entry
- Changed the format setting to 'Show Smart Paging settings during content editing of this content type'
- Added '< !--pagebreak-- >' to a blog post

I have done all of the above but the blog post still just shows the text that I have written all on one page with no 'next'/'previous' buttons. I'm hoping I've just missed something simple which someone could kindly point out to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The core 'book' module will do what you're after.

First, configure the module so that the content type you are using for blog posts is allowed to be in books at `admin/content/book/settings`.

Second, understand that a book is a bit like a menu, each page is a single node and the book simply provides the links between those nodes in order.  When you create or edit the node intended as the first page of your book go to the 'book outline' settings at the bottom of the node creation form and select `create new book`.

To add pages, create or edit the nodes that are to be the next page(s) and select the book you just created.

Finally there is a block that the module creates called 'book navigation', move that block to where you wish the 'next' and 'previous' links to go.

Some styling will probably be required if you want it to look like the example you gave.

Comment: We have the 'book' module installed but I cannot see an option to create the multiple page blog posts.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for: http://whatculture.com/film/10-biggest-movie-tv-news-week-sept-21.php

Comment: No worries, wasn't sure how much experience you had, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Darvanen. I'll have a go at that and let you know the results.